# Should "mathematics" be capitalized in the following examples?

Tags: capitalization

Should "mathematics" be capitalized in the following two cases:

> a Ph.D. program in (mathematics or Mathematics)
>
> the Ph.D. program in (mathematics or Mathematics). (referred to the
>   Ph.D. program in the Department of Mathematics in a university,
>   mentioned earlier)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Yes for both examples, if they are being used in a formal context.

> The Chicago Manual of Style (CMS) recommends writing academic degrees in lower case, except when using the degree as a title. ([Grammerbook.com](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/capitalization/capitalization-of-academic-degrees/))
>
> Capitalize abbreviations (B.A., M.S., M.B.A., Ph.D., etc.) and use periods. Capitalize complete names of degrees but do not capitalize when degrees are referred to informally. ([pdx.edu](http://www.pdx.edu/university-communications/editorial-style-guide-capitalization))

When *mathematics* is used in a sentence without specifically referring to the program of study of a university or a title, it is not capitalized.

> Supervision for MPhil/PhD research is available in computational learning theory, **financial mathematics**, stochastic control, search theory, and in the **applications of mathematics** in areas such as telecommunications and economics.

Here are some links that use both uppercase and lowercase versions of *mathematics.*

- http://math.berkeley.edu/programs/graduate/phd-program
- https://math.ucsd.edu/programs/graduate-program/phd-mathematics/index.html
- http://www.lse.ac.uk/maths/Degrees/PhD_and_MPhil.aspx
- http://math.nyu.edu/degree/phd/